# how to get thresholds for each probabilities for gender classification

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**I have a dataframe withgender probabilities**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'true_gender':['M','M','F','M','F','F','F','M','M','M'],\
              'male_probability':[0.51,0.67,0.29,0.81,0.76,0.43,0.56,0.61,0.48,0.21],\
              'female_probability':[0.49,0.33,0.71,0.19,0.24,0.57,0.44,0.39,0.52,0.79]})
```

**And i need to:**

1. get thresholders for each gender probability, when (TP+TN/F+P) accuracy=0.9 (threshold for male_probability and another threshold  for female_probability)
2. get single(general) threshold for both probabilities

**What i've tried to do:**

I got 90% of 'M' values
Then got the minimum threshold when accuracy for 'M' is 90%

```
df[df.true_gender=='M'].sort_values('male_probability', ascending=False).head(round(0.9*df[df.true_gender=='M'].shape[0]).iloc[-1,1]
```

But is seems to me that it's incorrectly method.

How can i calculate tresholders for each gender probabiity when accuracy=90% and general single thresholder (for both gender probabiity) when accuracy=90%?

I want to compare which format of thresholders better: single threshold for both probabilities or different thresholders for each gender

Comment: Actually, as i check there is not such a threshold. Are you sure? The best threshold I found is .7 in around male_probaility 43 to 47.

Comment: @keramat How did you calculated it? So, i need to calculate two kind of thresholds separately for each gender and single for two gender's. I guess you calculated a single threshold

Comment: It is lines of codes. Want to add as an answer?

Comment: Let's try please) But i need two kind of thresholds as you see

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'true_gender':['M','M','F','M','F','F','F','M','M','M'],\
              'male_probability':[0.51,0.67,0.29,0.81,0.76,0.43,0.56,0.61,0.48,0.21],\
              'female_probability':[0.49,0.33,0.71,0.19,0.24,0.57,0.44,0.39,0.52,0.79]})
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
for i in np.arange(0,1,.01):
    temp = np.where(df['male_probability']>i, 'M', 'F')
    if accuracy_score(df['true_gender'], temp)==.7:
        print(i, accuracy_score(df['true_gender'], temp))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is ".7"?  Any accuracy score ?

Comment: It is just for my experiment. You can ignore the if condition. Any way the code shows that there is not any greater possible accuracy than .7.

Comment: Thanks) If i need to calculate accuracy only for 'M' gender, how do i can do it?

Comment: There is not such a measure. You can use precision maybe which is the ratio of correct positive values to all samples labeled positive by the model.